# OWA has more autocomplete entries than Outlook (latest)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Why does the OWA (O365) have more autocomplete entries than my Outlook?
Is there a way to fix this or copy the autocomplete entries?

using latest version of Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete is just a local cache of email addresses you entered in Outlook or OWA online. The two will never be in sync. You must have done more email in OWA.

Autocomplete was not designed to be a contact list, rather just an aid to your work.

You can try one time retrieving OWA Autocomplete and replacing your Desktop Outlook autocomplete.

It may not be worth the effort, however.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2173254-retrieve-auto-complete-from-owa

Comment: how does a new profile of Outlook (latest, hosted on O365) still generate an Autocomplete list without sending an email?

Comment: The autocomplete list is store in the Windows User Profile, so a new Outlook profile will not change this.

Comment: What I"m asking is that if I create a NEW outlook profile using my O365 account - an autocomplete list DOES show up in Outlook without sending a first email.  where is this generated from?

Comment: Creating a new Outlook Profile does not delete the Autocomplete Entries store in the Windows User Profile here:  C:\Users\jusernameAppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache   .  This means you can move the standard Outlook Autocomplete to a new computer. That is independent of the Outlook Profile. So yes, if you create a new Outlook Profile, autocomplete will still be there.

Comment: thanks... also I think it might be AutoResolution kicking in.

Comment: According to this:  https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/understanding-address-autoresolution-autocomplete/#:~:text=You%20can%20force%20Outlook%20to,the%20names%2C%20but%20not%20immediately.  auto resolution is for older versions of Outlook (along with NK2 files). That may not be your issue here - not certain. But Autocomplete works as I noted above.